# waiting for debugger error in android

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

I just created a sample Hello world through Eclips in Windows. If i debug the application, emulator halts saying waiting for debugger,

Recently i updated to API 16 & 17.

here is the console message:

```
[2013-02-09 12:56:45 - helloworld] ------------------------------
[2013-02-09 12:56:45 - helloworld] Android Launch!
[2013-02-09 12:56:45 - helloworld] adb is running normally.
[2013-02-09 12:56:45 - helloworld] Performing com.example.helloworld.MainActivity activity launch
[2013-02-09 12:56:45 - helloworld] Automatic Target Mode: launching new emulator with compatible AVD 'FROYO'
[2013-02-09 12:56:45 - helloworld] Launching a new emulator with Virtual Device 'FROYO'
[2013-02-09 12:56:47 - helloworld] New emulator found: emulator-5554
[2013-02-09 12:56:47 - helloworld] Waiting for HOME ('android.process.acore') to be launched...
[2013-02-09 12:58:36 - helloworld] ------------------------------
[2013-02-09 12:58:36 - helloworld] Android Launch!
[2013-02-09 12:58:36 - helloworld] adb is running normally.
[2013-02-09 12:58:36 - helloworld] Performing com.example.helloworld.MainActivity activity launch
[2013-02-09 12:58:37 - helloworld] Automatic Target Mode: using existing emulator 'emulator-5554' running compatible AVD 'FROYO'
[2013-02-09 12:58:37 - helloworld] Uploading helloworld.apk onto device 'emulator-5554'
[2013-02-09 12:58:39 - helloworld] Installing helloworld.apk...
[2013-02-09 12:58:43 - helloworld] Success!
[2013-02-09 12:58:44 - helloworld] Starting activity com.example.helloworld.MainActivity on device emulator-5554
[2013-02-09 12:58:45 - helloworld] ActivityManager: Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=com.example.helloworld/.MainActivity }
```

Comment: Emulator hangs because of low system configuration..try debugging on device .

Answer (score -1):

Best solution is to get the fresh copy of ADT from Google and start development, its 399 MB only.

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't really answer the issue. The commend from Deepchand is more helpful.